# Why does the innerHTML property automatically trims the string?

Tags: javascript

here is my code:

```js
    function myFunction() {
    var str = "  Hello World  ";
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=str;
    alert(str);
    }
```

```html
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

While the Alert window outputs the string as it is i.e with spaces, the p element receives the string in trimmed form i.e with no spaces?

Answer (score 3):

In HTML, regular whitespace chararacters between tags are not interpreted as whitespaces to render by the browser.
Declaring one or multiple of them will give the same result: they are collapsed and are rendered as a single space.

To render multiple whitespaces, you have two ways :

- in plain HTML use the `&nbsp;` entity ( , or non-breaking space)
- in CSS, use the `white-space` property: `white-space: pre-wrap;`

**pre-wrap**

> Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline
>   characters, at [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br), and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Source: [MDN’s article on `white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values)

Comment: The problem with that approach is that lines can't get broken on that positions.

Comment: @Stephan It is a plain HTML way.  And this approach works. But anyway specifying both makes sense. I just added the CSS way too.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the innerHTML. Real culprit is  Browser. You cannot see the spaces in the browser directly with string literals as all browsers will always truncate spaces in HTML. You have use `&nbsp` to see them.

While browser processing your html, it follows some rules.

Here is the [16.6.1 The 'white-space' processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model)

> If 'white-space' is set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line',
>
> every tab (U+0009) is converted to a space (U+0020)
>
> any space (U+0020) following another space (U+0020) — even a space before the inline, if that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or 'pre-line' — is removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to see those whitespaces, you could use CSS's [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property and set it to `pre` (which breaks only on given line-breaks) or `pre-wrap` (which breaks whenever necessary).

However are you sure, that you really want to do positioning of text in HTML? Is there any reason that you leave the spaces and instead use `padding` on your element to shift its content?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser.

If you wanna be sure to have the space, do this:

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "  Hello World  ";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="&nbsp" + str + "&nbsp";
alert(str);
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: At first the &nbsp; are missing semicolons. Furthermore that renders two additional spaces even when `str` doesn't contain any spaces and too few spaces when it contains more that 2x2 spaces.